# Clear stored webdavs credentials from Dolphin (Kubuntu) not in KDE Wallet Manager

Tags: kubuntu, kde, authentication, dolphin, webdav

I've previously added a webdavs remote directory targeting Nextcloud in Dolphin on Kubuntu 20.4.3 using an URI such as `webdavs://user@local.domain:443/remote.php/dav/files/user/`.

Since then I've changed my password on Nextcloud, now Dolphin obviously fails to connect but does not ask for credentials again. The credentials are **not** available in the KDE wallet manager.

How do I clear the cached credentials for the webdavs directory in Dolphin?

Comment: They are to be found in your home directory, probably within an hidden directory. Sorry but I don't know where exactly.

Comment: Thanks for the hint @paladin, but I've scoured for anything with dolphin, credentials and webdav(s) in my home directory and couldn't find an appropriate file. Any idea or hint what I might be looking for there?

Answer (score 2):

I've closed all Dolphin processes, updated Kubuntu and reboot later Dolphin now asks for the credentials again. I still have no idea where those were cached and how I could have deleted them.

Comment: Same here. I also tried only stopping Dolphin processes (after closing Dolphin window in GUI, there are none left with Dolphin name in it though - kwalletd was running, which I also closed) -  that was not enough.
Updating the system was unnecessary for me though